# сtypes не видит DLL файл

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

У меня есть dll файл (`lib1.dll`), скомпилирован на gcc mingw 12.2.0. С помощью `ctypes` я подключаю эту библиотеку в код
Python:

```py
from ctypes import *
 
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\st2\\lib1.dll")
lib.print("Hello")
```

`lib1.cpp` (код dll):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
void print(string st){
    cout<<st;
}
```

И при попытке выполнить код выдается такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\st2\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    lib=cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\st2\\lib1.dll")
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\st2\lib1.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Все файлы в одной папке. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: *"Все файлы в одной папке."* - точно все? А то мало ли, вдруг там одна только lib1.dll лежит. А еще не забывайте про декорирование символов в С++. ctypes не работает с функциями С++.

Comment: @user7860670 не знаю, у меня в папке main.py, lib1.dll, а какие файлы нужны еще?

Comment: Проверьте, наличие файлов -зависимостей для lib1.dll. https://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: @Chorkov, я на 10 винде, а там нету для 10 версии,но я скачал. Открыл lib1.dll, файлы есть, правда я не знаю какие нужно увидеть. Древо есть

Comment: Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.

Comment: Сомневаюсь что это будет работать, учитывайте что `ctypes` был сделан для доступа ко функциям Си, а как сделать `std::string` из `str`, библиотека не знает, и не знает как демангулировать имя функции (на *nix оно должно быть `_Z5printNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import ctypes
ctypes.CDLL("lib1.dll",winmode=0)
```